# Retrieving Data from SQLite Database through AsyncTask and Displaying it

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-asynctask

So I have this program that I've been working on for the past few weeks that uses SQLite Database to store recipes added by a user that is run through AsyncTask and stored.  The recipes can be added and deleted but now I have to use AsyncTask to display the recipes entered within certain categories.  So for example if the user adds a "Bread" recipe, then on the home screen when the user clicks the "Bread" button, the recipe is displayed.  Here is what I have so far:

MyDBHandler.java:

```
package com.example.healthylife;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;


public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "recipeDB.db";
private static final String TABLE_RECIPE = "recipe";

private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
private static final String COLUMN_RECIPENAME = "_recipename";
private static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "_category";
private static final String COLUMN_INGREDIENTS = "_ingredients";
private static final String COLUMN_INSTRUCTIONS = "_instructions";

public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name,
                   SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    String CREATE_RECIPE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RECIPE + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_RECIPENAME + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_CATEGORY + " TEXT," + COLUMN_INGREDIENTS + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_INSTRUCTIONS + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_RECIPE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_RECIPE);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addRecipe(Recipe recipe){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_RECIPENAME, recipe.getRecipeName());
    values.put(COLUMN_CATEGORY, recipe.getCategory());
    values.put(COLUMN_INGREDIENTS, recipe.getIngredients());
    values.put(COLUMN_INSTRUCTIONS, recipe.getInstructions());

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_RECIPE, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public Recipe findRecipe(String recipename){
    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_RECIPE + "WHERE " + COLUMN_RECIPENAME + " = \"" +
            recipename + "\"";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    Recipe recipe = new Recipe();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        recipe.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        recipe.setRecipeName(cursor.getString(1));
        recipe.setCategory(cursor.getString(2));
        recipe.setIngredients(cursor.getString(3));
        recipe.setInstructions(cursor.getString(4));
        cursor.close();
    }else{
        recipe = null;
    }
    db.close();
    return recipe;
}

public boolean deleteRecipe(String recipename) {
    boolean result = false;

    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_RECIPE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_RECIPENAME + " = \"" +
            recipename + "\"";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    Recipe recipe = new Recipe();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        recipe.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        db.delete(TABLE_RECIPE, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(recipe.getID()) });
        cursor.close();
        result = true;
    }
    db.close();
    return result;
}

public Recipe getBread(String recipename) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_RECIPE + "WHERE " + COLUMN_RECIPENAME + " = \"" +
            recipename + "\"";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        recipe.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        recipe.setRecipeName(cursor.getString(1));
        recipe.setCategory(cursor.getString(2));
        recipe.setIngredients(cursor.getString(3));
        recipe.setInstructions(cursor.getString(4));
        cursor.close();
    }else{
        recipe = null;
    }
    db.close();
    return recipe;
}

public Recipe getFruit(String recipename) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_RECIPE + "WHERE " + COLUMN_RECIPENAME + " = \"" +
            recipename + "\"";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        recipe.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        recipe.setRecipeName(cursor.getString(1));
        recipe.setCategory(cursor.getString(2));
        recipe.setIngredients(cursor.getString(3));
        recipe.setInstructions(cursor.getString(4));
        cursor.close();
    }else{
        recipe = null;
    }
    db.close();
    return recipe;
}

public Recipe getVeg(String recipename) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_RECIPE + "WHERE " + COLUMN_RECIPENAME + " = \"" +
            recipename + "\"";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        recipe.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        recipe.setRecipeName(cursor.getString(1));
        recipe.setCategory(cursor.getString(2));
        recipe.setIngredients(cursor.getString(3));
        recipe.setInstructions(cursor.getString(4));
        cursor.close();
    }else{
        recipe = null;
    }
    db.close();
    return recipe;
}

public Recipe getSoup(String recipename) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_RECIPE + "WHERE " + COLUMN_RECIPENAME + " = \"" +
            recipename + "\"";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        recipe.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        recipe.setRecipeName(cursor.getString(1));
        recipe.setCategory(cursor.getString(2));
        recipe.setIngredients(cursor.getString(3));
        recipe.setInstructions(cursor.getString(4));
        cursor.close();
    }else{
        recipe = null;
    }
    db.close();
    return recipe;
}
```

[Recipe.java has the getters/setters]

The DatabaseActivity class uses the add and delete functions in AsyncTask:

```
package com.example.healthylife;



import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DatabaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


TextView idView;
EditText RecipeBox;
EditText CategoryBox;
EditText IngredientsBox;
EditText InstructionsBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_database);

    idView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Recipe_ID);
    RecipeBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_RecipeName);
    CategoryBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_category);
    IngredientsBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Ingredients);
    InstructionsBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Instructions);
}

public void newRecipe (View view){

    AsyncTaskSave op = new AsyncTaskSave();
    op.execute();

}

public void lookupRecipe (View view){
    MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);

    Recipe recipe = dbHandler.findRecipe(RecipeBox.getText().toString());

    if (recipe != null){
        idView.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getID()));

        CategoryBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getCategory()));
        IngredientsBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getIngredients()));
        InstructionsBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getInstructions()));
    }else {
        idView.setText("No Match Found");
    }
}

public void removeRecipe (View view){

    AsyncTaskDelete task = new AsyncTaskDelete();
    task.execute();
}

private class AsyncTaskSave extends AsyncTask <Object, Object, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object...objects){
        MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler (DatabaseActivity.this, null, null, 1);
        Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
        dbHandler.addRecipe(recipe);

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
        RecipeBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getRecipeName()));
        CategoryBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getCategory()));
        IngredientsBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getIngredients()));
        InstructionsBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getInstructions()));

        result = "Added Successfully";
        idView.setText(result);
    }
}

private class AsyncTaskDelete extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object...objects){
        MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler (DatabaseActivity.this, null, null, 1);
        dbHandler.deleteRecipe(null);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        if (result == null){
            idView.setText("Record Deleted");
            RecipeBox.setText("");
            CategoryBox.setText("");
            IngredientsBox.setText("");
            InstructionsBox.setText("");
        }else
            idView.setText("No Match Found");
    }
}

}
```

The SyncActivity.java class is supposed to display the recipes that were added by the DatabaseActivity class and call them on the screen when my main screen buttons are pressed:

```
package com.example.healthylife;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SyncActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

TextView idView;
TextView RecipeBox;
TextView CategoryBox;
TextView IngredientsBox;
TextView InstructionsBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sync);

    idView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Recipe_ID);
    RecipeBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_RecipeName);
    CategoryBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_category);
    IngredientsBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_Ingredients);
    InstructionsBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_Instructions);
}

public void getBread (View view) {

    AsyncTaskBread os = new AsyncTaskBread();
    os.execute();
}

public void getFruit (View view){
    AsyncTaskFruit ob = new AsyncTaskFruit();
    ob.execute();
}

public void getVeg (View view){
    AsyncTaskVeg ow = new AsyncTaskVeg();
    ow.execute();
}

public void getSoup (View view){
    AsyncTaskSoup ox = new AsyncTaskSoup();
    ox.execute();
}

private class AsyncTaskBread extends AsyncTask <Object, Object, String>{

    MyDBHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object...objects){
        MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler (SyncActivity.this, null, null, 1);
        dbHandler.getBread("Bread");
        return "Bread";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Recipe recipe = dbHandler.getBread(CategoryBox.getText().toString());

        if(recipe != null){
            idView.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getID()));
            RecipeBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getRecipeName()));
            IngredientsBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getIngredients()));
            InstructionsBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getInstructions()));
        }else {
            result = "No Match Found";
            idView.setText(result);
        }
    }
}

private class AsyncTaskFruit extends AsyncTask <Object, Object, String>{

    MyDBHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object...objects){
        MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler (SyncActivity.this, null, null, 1);
        dbHandler.getFruit("Fruit");
        return "Fruit";

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Recipe recipe = dbHandler.getFruit(CategoryBox.getText().toString());

        if(recipe != null){
            idView.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getID()));
            RecipeBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getRecipeName()));
            IngredientsBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getIngredients()));
            InstructionsBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getInstructions()));
        }else {
            result = "No Match Found";
            idView.setText(result);
        }
    }
}

private class AsyncTaskVeg extends AsyncTask <Object, Object, String>{

    MyDBHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object...objects){
        MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler (SyncActivity.this, null, null, 1);
        dbHandler.getVeg("Vegetables");
        return "Vegetables";

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Recipe recipe = dbHandler.getVeg(CategoryBox.getText().toString());

        if(recipe != null){
            idView.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getID()));
            RecipeBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getRecipeName()));
            IngredientsBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getIngredients()));
            InstructionsBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getInstructions()));
        }else {
            result = "No Match Found";
            idView.setText(result);
        }
    }
}

private class AsyncTaskSoup extends AsyncTask <Object, Object, String>{

    MyDBHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object...objects){
        MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler (SyncActivity.this, null, null, 1);
        dbHandler.getSoup("Soup");
        return "Soup";

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Recipe recipe = dbHandler.getSoup(CategoryBox.getText().toString());

        if(recipe != null){
            idView.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getID()));
            RecipeBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getRecipeName()));
            IngredientsBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getIngredients()));
            InstructionsBox.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getInstructions()));
        }else {
            result = "No Match Found";
            idView.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now here is the home screen:

[Home Screen in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZmaI.png)

When each button is clicked after the recipes are added in the recipe book, they should display details in certain fields but instead my fields are empty:

[Recipe call when buttons are clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXIei.png)

Now the SyncActivity class should be retrieving the values from the database that have been entered through the DatabaseActivity class but it isn't.  Is there something I need to change in the code in myDBHandler? Or is it in SyncActivity?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that private object dbHandler in class AsyncTaskBread for instance is never initialized. You initialize dbHandler in doInBackground, but that object lives only inside that function. Try changing line `MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler (SyncActivity.this, null, null, 1);` to `dbHandler = new MyDBHandler (SyncActivity.this, null, null, 1);` I would also advise you to move sql queries from onPostExecute to doInBackground, since onPostExecute runs on UI (main) thread.